# Pass Server Components to Client Components as Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to make an API call in my ServerComponent.js and return the data as props to the ClientComponent.js so i can have a frontpage that uses cached text content from an api. I don't want to make an API call each time the client lands on the frontpage.

I found this inside the docs:
[Nesting Server Components inside Client Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#nesting-server-components-inside-client-components)

So i made changes accordingly:

page.js

```
// page.js
import Home from './clientComponent'
import Server from './ServerComponent'
 
// Pages in Next.js are Server Components by default
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <Home>
      <Server />
    </Home>
  )
}
```

clientComponent.js

```
'use client'

import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from './page.module.css'


export default function Home({ children }) {


    return (
    <><main className={styles.main}>
        {children}
      </main>

    </>
  )

}
```

ServerComponent.js

```
import { API } from "../utils/api"; // Import your API constants


export default async function Server() {
  const data = await getData();
  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}


async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch(API.pages.retrieve(1));

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }

  const data = await res.json();


  return data;
}
```

All i get is:

```
- error Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {props}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

The idea is to ultimately use the array I'm getting like this:

```
    const set1 = data.textblockset.find(item => item.id === 1);

                {set1.textblock.map((item, index) => (
                    <>
                    {item.block_icon && (
                    <Image 
                        src={item.block_icon}
                        alt="icon"
                        width={50}
                        height={50}
                        loading="lazy"
                    />
                    )}
                    <Typography paragraph fontWeight="bold">
                        {item.block_title}
                    </Typography><br/>
                    <Typography>
                        {item.block_content}
                    </Typography>
                    </>
                ))}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Page` is already a server component, you can just load the data on the server-side there, and pass it down as props to the `Home` client component:

**`page.js:`**

```
import Home from './clientComponent';

export default async function Page() {
  const data = await getData();

  return (
    <Home data={ data  } />
  )
}
```

Note that the [`Page` component must be marked as `async`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-fetch):

```
export default async function Page() { ... }
```

**`clientComponent.js:`**

```
'use client';

export default function Home({ data }) {
  const set1 = data.textblockset.find(item => item.id === 1);

  return (
    <main className={ styles.main }>
      {
        set1.textblock.map((item, index) => (
          <Fragment key={ item.id }>
            { item.block_icon && (
              <Image 
                src={ item.block_icon }
                alt="icon"
                width={ 50 }
                height={ 50 }
                loading="lazy" />
            ) }

            <Typography paragraph fontWeight="bold">
              { item.block_title }
            </Typography>

            <Typography>
              { item.block_content }
            </Typography>
          </Fragment>
        ))
      }
    </main>
  )
}
```

Note from what I can see here, it looks like both of them could be server components, so I assume `Home` is still missing some functionality you didn't share in the snippet that justifies the need to make it a client component.

Comment: You mean by adding the API call to page.js? Or do I leave the API call inside the server component.js?

Comment: Yes. Client component has a few components in it that use state.

Comment: The `Page` component is already a server component. I don't see the need for an additional server component in this case, so yes, just move the API call to `page.js` and then pass `data` down to the `Home` client component.

Comment: Asking because whenever I run the exact same async function to fetch from the API inside page.js it will not return anything not even undefined when I use console log. It works fine inside the server component. It logs the response there.

Comment: @Matthias You are right, sorry. I noticed you were missing the `async` keyword in the `Home` component definition.